# Laravel 5.2 over EC2, CSS is not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am new to laravel, i pushed all the code to EC2 but when i change anything in my app.css file, my changes are not coming to user although app.css on EC2 have all those changes.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: its actually permission issue of storage folder.

Comment: put the errors and code so we can give you solution

Comment: which error and which code? i am not getting any error its just my css is not updating on page

Comment: In which folder you put your css file? and how you call css file in your blade template?

Comment: css folder is in public, css is loading perfectly fine, but the thing is when i update app.css and push it to EC2 my changes are not reflecting even though all those changes are there in app.css

Comment: So please check blade template where you call app.css and also the location app.css .Is it right way call or not check this? Then clear your browser history or try to another browser.Hope this will be worked.

Comment: isn't it a cache problem you are talking about? Are you using Elixir?

Comment: no i am not using elixir

Comment: not a browser issue either

Comment: When you right click on the browser after the page renders, are you able to see your updated css content in the app.css file?

If your css is present in the app.css, check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: [Check This link. might helps !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641371/is-it-possible-to-have-css-in-an-ec2-instance)