# Is it possible to have css in an ec2 instance

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

Using AWS I created an EC2 instance because I wanted to be able to execute php code. When I put my client side code in the /var/www/html folder, the html code comes up fine when I go to the public DNS. The css is not executed though. These are my permissions for my css file

`-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4236 Apr  4 00:08 home.css`

and this is the head tab in my html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css"></link>      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

[This link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72257) says I can use something called an S3 browser for my css, but does this mean I can't use an EC2 instance? Also from what I've look up about S3, it's a [windows application](http://s3browser.com/) and I'm using MACOS. It also looks like s3 is only for simple static web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the location of your CSS is incorrect. Assuming the HTML page is located at `/var/www/html/index.html`. Try changing the location of your css to `/css/home.css`

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css"></link>      
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Weird, I moved my css folder from /var/www/css to /var/www/html/css and it worked. I didn't even have to change `href="../css/home.css"` to `href="/css/home.css"`, but if I do change href it still works as wanted.

Comment: Glad it's working for you!  `/var/www/html` is the default public directory of most web servers like Apache. So anything under that (`/var/www`) is not public and can not be accessed through the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webserver installed on an Ec2 instance OR use S3 to host static files like CSS or Javascript. Those file permissions should allow a webserver to read the file.

You might want to try using the full DNS name to your css file in your HTML? `href="https://www.example.com/css/home.css"`